# Weird frame around image-button

Tags: html, css

I made an image-button which is hovering between to pictures. 
For some reason there is a frame around the picture when I set it as a  in html.

I've tried to change the button to just  and then the weird frame disappears but the the pressed down effect on to button doesn't work.

```css
.img {
  padding-left: auto;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("src/assets/red2.png")no-repeat;
}
.img:hover {
  padding-left: auto;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("src/assets/red1.png") no-repeat;
}

.img:active {
  background: url("src/assets/red1.png") no-repeat;
}
.img:focus {
  background: url("src/assets/red1.png") no-repeat;
}

.img:target {
  background: url("src/assets/red1.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<td>
 <button type=button (click)="" class="img"></button>
</td>
```

Comment: It's not really a 'weird' frame. It's the border that gives a button it's default 3D appearence. Set `img{border-width: 0;}` and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `border:0;` to get rid of the grey border and `outline: none;` if you want to get rid of the blue outline.

```css
.img {
  padding-left: auto;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("src/assets/redsmiley2.png")no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}
.img:hover {
  padding-left: auto;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("src/assets/redsmiley1.png") no-repeat;
}

.img:active {
  background: url("src/assets/redsmiley1.png") no-repeat;
}
.img:focus {
  background: url("src/assets/redsmiley1.png") no-repeat;
}

.img:target {
  background: url("src/assets/redsmiley1.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<td>
 <button type=button (click)="" class="img"></button>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @esso if any of the answers helped you, you should mark it as such. That will help other users as well

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
.img{
    border:0;
}
```

Also make sure the

```
<td>
```

tag is in a table.

Answer (score 0):

As GolezTrol stated, it's just the button default style to add a border.

What I use in these cases is simply

```
.img {
border: none;
outline: none;
}
```

This will ensure that the button has no border and also has no outline when active.